# Disable Google Analytics for Wildfly by configuration

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

How can I disable Google Analytics for the Wildfly 10 admin console using a configuration file or a command line parameter?

Redhat provides only documentation on how to disable the feature using the admin console:
[Enable/Disable Google Analytics in EAP Console](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/enabledisable_google_analytics_in_eap_console)

I could not find the corresponding code in the wildfly sources.

Comment: Are you talking for your own webapp?  Wildfly doesn't have GA enabled globally.

Comment: @stdunbar No, I'm talking about the Wildfly admin console. The option seems to be enabled by default. Disabling the option only sets a cookie in the browser of the user. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by running:

```
bin/standalone.sh -DCOLLECT_USER_DATA=false
```

It took a while to find this as the console after Wildfly 12 is based on [HAL](https://github.com/hal).  When you set the value via the console it only sets a cookie to disable it - it's not a permanent setting.  I was unable to find a place besides `standalone.conf` where I could make this change permanent. I had to add it to the JAVA_OPTS settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this does not work for Wildfly 10.